# List comprehension guard being ignored

Tags: python, list-comprehension, spacy

Lets say I have a `dict`:

```
d = {'AA': 'BB', 'BB': None}
```

And this `for comprehension`:

```
[v for t in u'{}'.format(v.lower()) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Its obvious that its going to fail with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`, so lets try this one:

```
[v for t in u'{}'.format(v.lower()) for k, v in d.items() if v is not None]
```

The same happens!, Why? If I add another guard:

```
[v for t in u'{}'.format(v.lower()) if v is not None for k, v in d.items() if v is not None]
```

Same thing.

Why is `v.lower()` being called even with the guards?

However, this works:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if v is not None:
        [v for t in u'{}'.format(v.lower())]
```

## Update

This is the actual code that is giving me the problem, The above code was to simplify the example, but given that the answer provided below, I think I will post the actual code:

```
x = {'A': 'This is a Line to Be tokenized'}
for k,v in x.items():
    if v is not None:
        pat = [{'LOWER': str(t)} for t in tokenizer(u'{}'.format(v.lower()))]
```

This generate patters for Spacy, in this format:

```
[{'LOWER': 'this'},
 {'LOWER': 'is'},
 {'LOWER': 'a'},
 {'LOWER': 'line'},
 {'LOWER': 'to'},
 {'LOWER': 'be'},
 {'LOWER': 'tokenized'}]
```

So, originally my for comprehension to generate that output is

```
[{'LOWER': str(t)} for k, v in x.items() if v is not None for t in tokenizer(u'{}'.format(v))]
```

But, as mentioned above, when the `value` of the dictionary is `None`, it fails even when a `guard` is provided.

## Update 2

Here are more examples:

```
x = {'A': 'This is a Line to Be tokenized', 'B': 'Hello'}
for k,v in x.items():
    if v is not None:
        pat = [{'LOWER': str(t)} for t in tokenizer(u'{}'.format(v.lower()))]
        print(pat)

# [{'LOWER': 'this'}, {'LOWER': 'is'}, {'LOWER': 'a'}, {'LOWER': 'line'}, {'LOWER': 'to'}, {'LOWER': 'be'}, {'LOWER': 'tokenized'}]
# [{'LOWER': 'hello'}]
```

So, basically I want to convert that loop into a comprehension.

Comment: I your first example, the fors are in the wrong order

Comment: `[v.lower() if v is not None else v for k, v in d.items()]` ?

Comment: `[v.lower() if v else v for k, v in d.items()]` also you don't need to call `str.lower` for each character... why not the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written as follows:

```
x = {'A': 'This is a Line to Be tokenized', 'B':None}
for k,v in x.items():
    if v is not None:
        pat = [{'LOWER': str(t)} for t in tokenizer(u'{}'.format(v.lower()))]


res = [[{'LOWER': str(t)} for t in tokenizer(u'{}'.format(v.lower()))] for k, v in x.items() if v is not None]
```

Output:

```
[[{'LOWER': 'this'},
  {'LOWER': 'is'},
  {'LOWER': 'a'},
  {'LOWER': 'line'},
  {'LOWER': 'to'},
  {'LOWER': 'be'},
  {'LOWER': 'tokenized'}]]
```

However, at this point, you do not gain a lot from writing it in a single line, but lose a lot in terms of readability. I would encourage you not to write this in a single line.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for performance to write it as a comprehension instead of a for loop?

Comment: only barely, and its generally not noticeable enough to matter. @ElBaulP if you give up readability at any stage, normal loops are preferred.

Comment: Perfect then, I will leave it as you mentioned in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the order of the `for`s and `if`s:

```
>>> [v for k, v in d.items() if v is not None for t in u'{}'.format(v.lower())]
['BB', 'BB']
>>>
```

- The `if` statement has to be before the location where it's gonna cause an error.
- The second `for` loop has to be after the `for` loop which contains the iterators that the second `for` loop uses.

Comment: I am going to update my example, as it wasn´t the real one, I need the for comprehension to have that structure.